# How to map and change the value inside the array?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I'm wondering how I could check each iteration of the role type and change the value and change it accordingly depending on the type of role.

```
array = [
 {
id: "1",
role: "User"
},
{
id: "2",
role : "Provider"
},
{
id: "3",
role: "Administration"
}
]

// If role: User, change to role: "Disable"
// If role: Provider, change role to "Read Me"
// If role Administration, change role to "Admin"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
let array = [
    {
        id: "1",
        role: "User"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        role : "Provider"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        role: "Administration"
    }
];

let roleMappings = {
    User: "Disable",
    Provider: "Read Me",
    Administration: "Admin"
};

let result = array.map( value => {
    value.role = roleMappings[value.role];
    return value;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a simple `forEach` loop and check the roles and then change them accordingly.

```js
let arr = [
 {
   id: "1",
   role: "User"
 },
 {
   id: "2",
   role : "Provider"
 },
 {
   id: "3",
   role: "Administration"
 }
];

arr.forEach(obj => {
  // check for whatever value you need
  if (obj.role === 'User') {
    // change the value
    obj.role = 'abc';
  }
  // add more checks if needed
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.forEach(function(val,index){
var newRole ="";
if(val.role == 'User') {
   newRole = 'Disable';
}else if(val.role == 'Provider'){
   newRole = 'Read Me';
}

});
```

I am not sure what do you mean by changing the role. But based on existing role of every object if you want to change the access control then above code will help you.
you can also use the switch case instead of if else.